Why did static magnets make ice melt faster?
I made the following pilot experiment. I made 2 cubes of ice 3x4x5 cm (HxWxL) from tap water in 2 containers obtained from a cheese package (it has silver-looking reflective interior and is made from carton). So all ice-cube surfaces except one were covered by the interior of this container and one surface was facing the room temperature air.
I placed one container with the ice cube on a pile of static magnets (it was like at least 3 1x2 cm silver-looking magnets and a couple of larger black static magnets attracted together in one pile). The overall static magnetic field was at least ~3x stronger (up to maybe 7x) than the Earth's background.
The control ice cube was placed at ~15cm distance from the one affected by the static MF.
So, the ice cube placed on top of the pile of static magnets melted ~10-20% faster.
I know that static magnetic field is created by these magnets due to the spins of their electrons aligned in one direction. Generally I would expect an alternating EMF to make ice melt faster. Can you explain why did the static magnetic field made ice melt faster?

Get a second identical pile of magnets, and raise them above their Curie temperature to destroy their permanent magnetism. Do the two piles' blocks now melt at the same rate? Probably the magnets have a greater thermal conductivity than whatever material was in contact with your control (what material would that have been?). The magnetism itself is incidental.

Both containers with the ice cubes were placed on a wooden plate. The control was in contact with the reflective interior surface of the carton container and one surface of the control - with the room temp air, the container - with the wooden plate.

So I can also rather place the ice cube above the magnets in the radius of the static MF rather than directly on the magnets?

The experimental ice cube was in direct contact with the carton container only, and the container was in contact with the magnet pile

The control was in direct contact with the carton container, and the container - with the wooden plate

Greater thermal conductivity of magnets is a good explanation, so will try to place the ice cube above them to be in contact with the MF only

According to this paper, the freezing point of water can increase in the presence of a magnetic field. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2194/1/012034/pdf

I've already replicated the pilot experiment with experimental ice cube lifted ~2cm above the magnets stack so that it was under the effect of magnetic field and did not contact with the magnets. And it still melted faster. It melted completely, while the control cube had ~8x8mm blob remaining. Both ice cubes were in identical plastic containers, the control was 15cm distance away from the magnets, I checked the MF strength with smartphone EMF meters, so the experimental cube received ~3-10x more MF.

Gemini: "The research suggests a magnetic field can also raise the melting point of water slightly. So, in theory, an ice cube under a strong magnetic field could melt a little slower than one without.
However, the same caveats from before apply:
The effect is small and requires strong magnetic fields.
The mechanism isn't fully understood.
Other factors like temperature likely have a bigger impact."


The whole setup with 2 ice cubes was placed at ~40cm near the window with 2 vent openings opened. The experimental cube was the closest to them, but the window and the vents were slightly opened the whole day, so the temperature gradient should have been established and should not have had a big impact. I may repeat and post in another post.

The magnets are metallic, so they are better heat conductors. Just repeat your experiment with some non magnetic material like copper, it will melt even  faster. So it has nothing to do with magnetism.

I am researching the effects of electric and magnetic fields on biophysical systems and would like my hypotheses to be confirmed experimentally. I believe that copper in contact with the ice would make ice melt faster as copper is used in heat transfer tube to cool CPUs. I repeated as described in the comment above, and made the ice to be under the effect of MF only and with no contact with the magnets. And the ice still melted faster.

Ifyou really want the influence of the magnets, two ways. 1. cool then to 0°C, or 2. hang them over the ice, so there is no immediate   or indirect  contact  to the ice.
